# How to add option to make a file executable in PCManFM's context menu?

Tags: executable, pcmanfm, context-menu

Nautilus and Thunar have a such context menu option under Properties/Permissions, but not PCManFM, Lubuntu's default file and desktop manager (at least not yet in the present v. 1.1.).

But under "Open with"/(again)"Open with"/"Custom command line", it is possible to add new custom commands.

[image]

[image]

This creates a file with extension `.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` which can be edited further so as to get a proper name and icon.

What is the command to add in this way for making a file executable?

That is: how to use `sudo chmod +x filename` to make it work in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Considering the example from the answer - of using the "Open with" option:**

The command `sudo chmod +x` must run in a terminal (`gnome-terminal -e "sudo chmod +x %f"`) or alternatively the line `Terminal=true` should be in a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/make_exec.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Make file executable
Exec=sudo chmod +x %f 
Icon=path/to/icon
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

For an application to appear in the context menu, it may need a desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, but also you may need to edit as administrator `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` and in the line of the intended file type to add the *application*.desktop.

So, in the present case, open `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` and add `make_exec.desktop` to the line `text/plain`.

---

**Considering the creation of custom actions - like in Thunar, Nautilus or Dolphin:**

**PCManFM supports custom actions.**

Those created with Nautilus configuration tool (for Nautilus) appear in PCManFM too. These are .desktop files created in `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions`. So, they can be added manually without the Nautilus tool.

The form of these files should be like those presented [here](http://forum.slitaz.org/topic/custom-actions-in-the-pcmanfm) or [here](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM#Add_own_options_to_the_files_context_menu).

So, for the present purpose, create the file `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/make_executable.desktop` with these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name = Make executable
Tooltip = Make this file executable
Icon = terminal
Profiles = make_exec;

[X-Action-Profile make_exec]
Name = Make executable
MimeTypes = text/plain;
SelectionCount = 1
Schemes = file;
Exec = sudo chmod +x %f
```