# PCmanFM - How can I remove an entry from the context menu?

Tags: lubuntu, mime-type, pcmanfm, context-menu

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

When clicking right on a file the context menu of the file manager opens up. The file manager is PCmanFM, a great tool. I would like to remove programs from the list of suggested programs to open a certain file with.

For example a text file can be opened with Leafpad and with AbiWord in the default installation of Lubuntu 18, already.

I understand that the entries result from several ways of adding them. Adding such an entry seems to be easier then removing one.

Is there a documentation of the several ways on how to remove entries in context menu of PCmanFM?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways in which that list is created. Some applications ar associated by default (or they associate themselves when installed) to a certain file type or to folders. In this case they are listed in that file's or folder's mime-type line in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` or `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`.

After selecting the "Open with" option in order to use a new application, that is then added in the same way to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

---

- In order to completely remove an application from the list, remove it from the  line corresponding to a specific mime-type in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` or `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` or  `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.
- In order to downgrade the application in the list (keep it but put a different one on top of the list), use again 'Open with' to select a new application or command — even using a command line option, as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/251141/925128).

In this way one can also fix temporarily the Firefox bug of opening downloads folder with a media player or other unsuitable program.